# Flink Dynamic Update Stream job

Tags: java, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am receiving a set of events in Avro format on different topics. I want to consume these and write to s3 in parquet format. 
I have written a below job that creates a different stream for each event and fetches it schema from the confluent schema registry to create a parquet sink for an event.
This is working fine but the only problem I am facing is whenever a new event start coming I have to change in the YAML config and restart the job every time. Is there any way I do not have to restart the job and it start consuming a new set of events.

```
YamlReader reader = new YamlReader(topologyConfig);
    EventTopologyConfig eventTopologyConfig = reader.read(EventTopologyConfig.class);

    long checkPointInterval = eventTopologyConfig.getCheckPointInterval();
        topics = eventTopologyConfig.getTopics();

                List<EventConfig> eventTypesList = eventTopologyConfig.getEventsType();

        CachedSchemaRegistryClient registryClient = new CachedSchemaRegistryClient(schemaRegistryUrl, 1000);


        FlinkKafkaConsumer flinkKafkaConsumer = new FlinkKafkaConsumer(topics,
        new KafkaGenericAvroDeserializationSchema(schemaRegistryUrl),
        properties);

        DataStream<GenericRecord> dataStream = streamExecutionEnvironment.addSource(flinkKafkaConsumer).name("source");

        try {
        for (EventConfig eventConfig : eventTypesList) {

        LOG.info("creating a stream for ", eventConfig.getEvent_name());

final StreamingFileSink<GenericRecord> sink = StreamingFileSink.forBulkFormat
        (path, ParquetAvroWriters.forGenericRecord(SchemaUtils.getSchema(eventConfig.getSchema_subject(), registryClient)))
        .withBucketAssigner(new EventTimeBucketAssigner())
        .build();

        DataStream<GenericRecord> outStream = dataStream.filter((FilterFunction<GenericRecord>) genericRecord -> {
        if (genericRecord != null && genericRecord.get(EVENT_NAME).toString().equals(eventConfig.getEvent_name())) {
        return true;
        }
        return false;
        });
        outStream.addSink(sink).name(eventConfig.getSink_id()).setParallelism(parallelism);

        }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Yaml file :

```
!com.bounce.config.EventTopologyConfig
eventsType:
  - !com.bounce.config.EventConfig
    event_name: "search_list_keyless"
    schema_subject: "search_list_keyless-com.bounce.events.keyless.bookingflow.search_list_keyless"
    topic: "search_list_keyless"

  - !com.bounce.config.EventConfig
    event_name: "bike_search_details"
    schema_subject: "bike_search_details-com.bounce.events.keyless.bookingflow.bike_search_details"
    topic: "bike_search_details"

  - !com.bounce.config.EventConfig
    event_name: "keyless_bike_lock"
    schema_subject: "analytics-keyless-com.bounce.events.keyless.bookingflow.keyless_bike_lock"
    topic: "analytics-keyless"

  - !com.bounce.config.EventConfig
      event_name: "keyless_bike_unlock"
      schema_subject: "analytics-keyless-com.bounce.events.keyless.bookingflow.keyless_bike_unlock"
      topic: "analytics-keyless"


checkPointInterval: 1200000

topics: ["search_list_keyless","bike_search_details","analytics-keyless"]
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use a custom BucketAssigner that uses the `genericRecord.get(EVENT_NAME).toString()` value as the bucket ID, along with whatever event time bucketing was being done by the `EventTimeBucketAssigner`.

Then you don't need to create multiple streams, and it should be dynamic (whenever a new event name value occurs in a record being written, you'll get a new output sink).

Comment: Thanks . I m creating multiple streams because of different avro schema record and i have to create sink with corresponding schema.

Comment: Ok, sorry. That makes it harder. I _think_ you could still do it along the lines I said above, by also creating your own PartFileFactory that would use your BucketID class to create the appropriate writer, based on the schema.

Comment: can you provide some reference code on how to implement my own PartFileFactory or if you can provide some sample code that will help.

Comment: Don't have any sample code, sorry. The Flink source code has an implementation of the PartFileFactory, which is where I'd start.

Comment: There is no way so that I can keep updating my YAML file with some frequent intervals.